# how to pick the return value from previous task of python operator in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

while trying to capture the output of a task of python operator into a variable getting error. Any suggestion pls

```
with DAG(
        dag_id="test_dag",
        start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 24),
        schedule_interval=None,
        render_template_as_native_obj=True,
        default_args={},
        params={
            "param2": "arya2@gmail.com",
            "sourcedir": ['/home/arya/'],
            "timenum": 0
        },
        catchup=False
) as dag:

    pythondefination = PythonOperator(
                    task_id=f"pythondefinationfunc",
                    python_callable=pythondefination,
                    provide_context=True
                    )

    def valuecapture(**kwargs):
        ti  = kwargs['ti']
        timeinfo = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='pythondefinationfunc')
        return timeinfo
        
        
    **Error: KeyError: 'ti'
```

Comment: where did you call the method `valuecapture`? you should run it in an operator

Comment: @HusseinAwala .. Thanks a lot.. As i need to pass timeinfo as a variable to other bash operator command

Answer (score 0):

To access the return value from the previous task, you can read it from xcom, but the read should be in an airflow operator in order to access the run context:

```py
bash_task = BashOperator(
    task_id="read_python_func_return_value",
    bash_command="echo {{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='pythondefinationfunc')}}",
)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply. Can we capture xcom_pull value to a variable as because i have few more steps where i have to concatenate and then pass them

Comment: you have the syntax, it works for all the operators, and you can pull it multiple time, if you want to concatenate it with other xcom in the same command it's possible and if you want to store it in bash variable it's also possible`var={{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='pythondefinationfunc')}} && echo $var`, but if you want to store in a variable outside the operators, this is not possible and it's useless where you can pull it when you want